# Regex match last occurrence between 2 strings

Tags: regex

I have a string like this:

```
abcabcdeabc...STRING INSIDE...xyz
```

I want to find "...STRING INSIDE..." so I'm using the regex below to match it:

```
(?<=abc).*(?=xyz)
```

The issue is there are duplicated "abc" in the string so it returns "abcdeabc...STRING INSIDE..." but I only want to match anything between the last "abc" and "xyz". Is this possible? And if yes, how can I achieve this? Thank you.

Try it here:
https://regex101.com/r/gS9Xso/3

Comment: What tool/language are you using?  This is important information, because it might influence the pattern we give you as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
.*(?<=abc)(.*)(?=xyz)
```

The leading `.*` will consume everything up until the last `abc`, then the number will be captured.

### Demo

We can also try using the following pattern:

```
.*abc(.*?)xyz
```

Here is a demo for the second pattern:

### Demo

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gS9Xso/1/ The pattern seems doesn't work for this case. And I actually want to capture anything between them, not just numbers. Could you please follow the link and try again?

Comment: @LouisTran Both of my patterns work, check the demo links.  There is something wrong with your demo.

Comment: I'm sorry for my confusing description. I want to match anything between the last "abc" and "xyz". Not just number. Your second pattern works but it only match the number, not letter and others.

Comment: My first pattern should still work for you.  What tool/language are you using here?

Comment: Thank you. You are right. It works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This should work well.

```
[^\d]*abc(\d+)xyz[^\d]*
```

See it on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/i3mVpi3KkmGwqmio)